# If I replace the stock clutch and flywheel in an RX-7 to JDM after market models, do I need to calibrate the gears

Tags: clutch

I was watching a video on Youtube, the source of all information, and I watched these people replace the clutch and the flywheel of the transmission because it was in less than ideal condition. They never explained if it had to be done. I do know if you replace the stock coil-overs from a car and put in, let's say fortune auto race coil-overs with camber, you have to realign. I didn't know if the clutch was like that.

Comment: My first choice for "the source of all information" for my car is the manufacturers workshop manual. Any and I mean ANY other source is checked thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't do anything to the gearbox when you replace the clutch and flywheel.  The manual transmission is a self-contained unit and the only interface to the clutch is via the input shaft.

There is no such thing as "gear calibration" anyway, at least not in a normal manual transmission.

Comment: OP may be referring to speedometer calibration but that would only need to be if the wheels were aftermarket bigger or smaller

Comment: I didn't get that but who knows?